# Pragrammatically set device orientation for particular viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios10

I want to set device orientation to landscape mode programmatically to particular viewcontroller, its working well if I use with UIAlertController, with YES/NO option, but if I directly write the same code on button click. its not working.

working code with UIAlertController,

```
 UIAlertController * alert=[UIAlertController
alertControllerWithTitle:APP_NAME message:@"Please Select Video Orientation."preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

 UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                                    actionWithTitle:@"Landscape Mode"
                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                    {
                                        NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
                                        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
                                        [self.navigationController pushViewController:mySecondViewController animated:NO];
                                    }];
 UIAlertAction* noButton = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:@"Portrait Mode"
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                   {
                                       NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
                                       [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
                                       [self.navigationController pushViewController:mySecondViewController animated:NO];
                                   }];

 [alert addAction:yesButton];
 [alert addAction:noButton];

 [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The above code is working well, but i want to force next controller in landscape mode without asking with Alert, so directly write the code on button click like this,

```
  NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
  [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:mySecondViewController animated:NO];
```

but this same code is not working well. it will open the mySecondViewController in portrait first and manually we have to tilt phone once then it will move into landscape.

I tried lot of option but no luck. Testing on iPhone5 and iPhone6 with iOS 10.1

---

**Update: adding mySecondViewController code,**
This is second view controller code,

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    // [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft|UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for force the view to launch in landscape mode in swift :
Use this code in viewWillAppear

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(Int(value), forKey: "orientation")
```

and

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is code for set orientation, but if you want for specific VC try this code in that VC class

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:
[NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]
    forKey:@"orientation"];
```

Comment: `[UIViewController attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation];`

should be called after the above line.